# Beginner to Quartz.NET and need some guidance

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I posted last night stating that I was creating a Windows Service with the task of moving various files around, by being given specified paths (network shares, ftp servers, http servers) and a regex of the fles to be moved. These tasks will be added via an ASP.NET interface, and the actual service will be in C#.

After some suggestions I decided to look into Quartz.NET, and it seems perfect for the purpose. I'm having a very difficult time wrapping my hed around it all though - I've set it up so the jobs are stored in a database, and ran the inbuilt SQL queries to make the tables. Where do I go from here? How do I go about defining what types of jobs there may be, and is it possible for jobs to be inputted to the database via an ASP.NET web page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz.NET, at the time of writing, is equivalent to [Java Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) 1.6.6 so don't be afraid to [download this version](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/download/quartz-1.6.6.zip) and use their html documentation, tutorials and code examples if you're not satisfied with the what you have at the moment.